# C# trigger a function on mouse click from another window

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to trigger a function when i click anywhere inside another specific window. 
example:
 When i clicked something in windows calculator i want to trigger a function in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are clicking on windows that means you are setting focus to windows. If you want to call a function when form is clicked then you have to use form activate event. For your scenario i am assuming that  calculator is sitting inside panel. if that is the case you need to call your function in click event of panel.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about events from his own application but rather any application (like Calc or Notepad) that is running alongside which will make things very different and far more complicated.